# Dashing Dashboard Framework Passing Label & Value to a List Widget

Tags: ruby, sinatra, dashing

To pass data into the view, the generic "job" is set up as so:

```
SCHEDULER.every '1m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  send_event('widget_id', { })
end
```

In the view, it is processed as such:

```
<li data-foreach-item="items">
  <span class="label" data-bind="item.label"></span>
  <span class="value" data-bind="item.value"></span>
</li>
```

I am not sure how to pass in a hash (or more broadly, collection) that is able to be read in that label, value format. If someone could point me in the right direction I sure would appreciate it. I can't find any helpful documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've not used Dashing (although it looks quite interesting).

From the docs:

> …
>   send_event('karma', { current: rand(1000) })
>   …
>
> This job will run every minute, and will send a random number to ALL
>   widgets that have data-id set to 'karma'.
>
> You send data using the following method:
>
> send_event(widget_id, json_formatted_data)

So for your collection, you need an array of hashes, each hash has the keys `label` and `value` (as instance method calls on an object in coffeescript are (in Ruby speak) really just [accessors on a hash](http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html)).

Once you have that collection, transform it into JSON, and stick it in an object with the accessor `items`, e.g.

```
require 'json'
items = [{label: "l1", value: "v1"},{label: "l2", value: "v2"},{label: "l3", value: "v3"}]
json_formatted_items = items.to_json
# => "[{\"label\":\"l1\",\"value\":\"v1\"},{\"label\":\"l2\",\"value\":\"v2\"},{\"label\":\"l3\",\"value\":\"v3\"}]"

SCHEDULER.every '1m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  send_event('widget_id', {items: json_formatted_items })
end
```

I don't know if that will work, but that's what I think will work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is quite deceiving though, you pass in an array with a Hash

Here is what i did to use a List

```
buzz  = [{:label=>"Count", :value=>10}, { :label=>"Sort", :value=>30}]
 send_event('buzzwords', { items: buzz })
```

The above works, but if i do the following :

```
buzz  = [{:label=>"Count", :value=>10}, { :label=>"Sort", :value=>30}]
items = buzz.to_json
send_event('buzzwords', { items: items})
```

That does not work, but the documentation says `send_event(widget_id, json_formatted_data)`
The `item` is json formatted but that does not work, instead pass in an array with a Hash

Comment: this answer was the most helpful. I spent some time hacking around trying to figure out why my perfectly formatted json wasn't actually making it to my dashboard... turns out to be an *array of hashes*. Made the change, and **poof**, it magically worked.

Comment: I'm in this same pickle, do you by chance have sample git I can view? I have a lib/.rb file with my hashes that I wish to call in the jobs. But, aren't named in the same namaculture (label, value). Rather timestamp, top, bottom, average with values, as am building a multi-linechart